# Do a rolling sum of a columns using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation, rolling-sum

I need to do a rolling sum of a columns of a dataframe, verify if the sum of the rolling (2 to 5 lines) is = 0 and take all the lines from the rolling to flag them as "canceled".

I tried this :

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values('No Piece FI')
df_sorted['No Piece FI'] = df_sorted['No Piece FI'].astype(str)
df = df_sorted[df_sorted['No Piece FI'].str.startswith('11')]
rolling_sum = df['CP'].rolling(window=5, min_periods=2).sum().shift(-4)
df.loc[(rolling_sum == 0), 'Annulé'] = 'Canceled'
```

But when I do that the result didn't seems to works. Also I would like to see the lines number like that or at least the group :

| Annulé | Lines | CP | Group (optionnal) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Not canceled |  | 8 |  |
| Not canceled |  | 4 |  |
| Canceled | 1 | 10 | 1 |
| Canceled | 2 | -10 | 1 |
| Not canceled |  | 3 |  |
| Canceled | 1 | 15 | 2 |
| Canceled | 2 | -5 | 2 |
| Canceled | 3 | -10 | 2 |
| Canceled | 1 | 8 | 3 |
| Canceled | 2 | -8 | 3 |
| Not canceled |  | 19 |  |
| Not canceled |  | 3 |  |
| Not canceled |  | 2 |  |
| Canceled | 1 | -8 | 4 |
| Canceled | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| Canceled | 3 | 2 | 4 |
| Canceled | 4 | 1 | 4 |
| Canceled | 5 | 3 | 4 |
| Not canceled |  | -1024 |  |

Here is what only the input would looks like :

| CP |
| --- |
| 8 |
| 4 |
| 10 |
| -10 |
| 15 |
| -5 |
| -10 |
| 8 |
| -8 |
| 19 |
| 3 |
| 2 |
| -8 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 3 |

How can I do that ? Thanks you.

Comment: You should provide a clear reproducible input for us to be able to run your code.

Comment: Input are in the "CP" columns, 10 + -10 = 0 so we take those 2 lines and we call them canceled. 10 is lines 1 of the rolling and -10 is line 2 of the rolling. We didn't go further because it's equal 0. I want to go to 5 lines in my rolling, no more.

Comment: In your example, shouldn't your lines 4 and 5 be numbered 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes you're right, I corrected, thanks you

Comment: What should happen to the lines where CP doesn't cancel?

Comment: They should just not be marked as "canceled".

Answer (score 1):

I used your example for the following code. It should help do what you want, except every line has a line number and a group number which makes things way easier. It's more of a partial answer as I haven't tested other inputs.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Using your example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'CP': [10, -10, 15, -5, -10, 8, -8, 19, 3, 2]})

output_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Annulé', 'Lines', 'CP', 'Group'])

line_counter = 1
output_line_counter = 0
group_counter = 1

rolling_sum = df['CP'].rolling(window=5, min_periods=2).sum()

for i in range(len(df)):
    if rolling_sum[i] == 0:
        output_df.loc[output_line_counter] = ['Canceled', line_counter, df.loc[i, 'CP'], group_counter]
        output_df.loc[output_df.Group == group_counter, 'Annulé'] = "Canceled"
        group_counter+= 1
        output_line_counter += 1
        line_counter = 1
    else:
        output_df.loc[output_line_counter] = ['', line_counter, df.loc[i, 'CP'], group_counter]
        output_line_counter += 1
        line_counter += 1

print(output_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html), identify the points in which the cumulated sum is null and backtrack the groups:

```
m = df['CP'].cumsum().eq(0)[::-1]
g = m.cumsum()

out = (df[m.cummax()] # keep only the rows until the sum cancels last
       .assign(Annulé='Canceled',
               Lines=g[::-1].groupby(g).cumcount().add(1))
      )
```

Output:

```
   CP    Annulé  Lines
0  10  Canceled      1
1 -10  Canceled      2
2  15  Canceled      1
3  -5  Canceled      2
4 -10  Canceled      3
5   8  Canceled      1
6  -8  Canceled      2
```

Comment: I think i've not explained well. Sometimes there are CP that didn't cancel. That's why I said max 5 in my rolling. Thanks

Comment: Please update your example

Comment: I've updated it, sorry